# In Slick 3.0, how to simplify nested `db.run`?

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0

I'm using Slick 3.0, and following is my codes:

```
def registerMember(newMember: TeamMember): Future[Long] = {

  db.run(
    teamProfileTable.filter(u => u.ID === newMember.ID).result.headOption
  ).flatMap {
    case None => Future(-1)
    case _ => db.run(
      (teamProfileTable returning teamProfileTable.map(_.staffID)) += newMember.toTeamRecord
    )
  }
}
```

This may look ok. But when there are more layers of callback, the codes may become hard to read. I tried to simplify the codes using `for-expression` or `andThen`.. But due to the pattern matching part, I can only use `flatMap` to implement this..

Does anyone have ideas about how to refactor this?

Comment: You should combine the queries and then only as the last step run the composition on the db. This is how I think it's supposed to work. If you add some more code to make a runnable example I could give it a try with an answer.

Comment: @pagoda_5b Thanks! But how to combine the two queries if the second query depends on the result of first query? I think `andThen` is not suitable here..

Comment: @hanfeisun You should probably use for comprehensions, but I can't help you further if you can't provide some self-consistent code to test. I may only guess the intent and the result of your code unless you're more explicit. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a for comprehension should be okay here, you just need conditional handling of the `Option` in the result of the first `Future`.  Something like this should work (note I did not compile check this):

```
def registerMember(newMember: TeamMember): Future[Long] = {

  for{
    r1Opt <- db.run(teamProfileTable.filter(u => u.ID === newMember.ID).result.headOption
    r2 <- r1Opt.fold(Future.successful(-1L))(r1 => db.run((teamProfileTable returning teamProfileTable.map(_.staffID)) += newMember.toTeamRecord)
  } yield r2

}
```

You can see on the right side of the `fold` that I have access to the result of the first `Future` if it was a `Some` (as `r1`).

I would even take this a step further and create separate methods for the steps of the for comprehension to clean things up, like so:

```
def registerMember(newMember: TeamMember): Future[Long] = {
  def findMember = 
    db.run(teamProfileTable.filter(u => u.ID === newMember.ID).result.headOption

  def addMember(r1Opt:Option[TeamMember]) = {
    r1Opt.fold(Future.successful(-1L)){r1 =>
      db.run((teamProfileTable returning teamProfileTable.map(_.staffID)) += 
        newMember.toTeamRecord)
    }
  }

  for{
    r1Opt <- findMember
    r2 <- addMember(r1Opt)
  } yield r2

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to simplify nested db.runs in Slick 3.0 when the query spans two tables could be to join the queries into a single query. [Joining and Zipping](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.0.0/queries.html#joining-and-zipping). However, the OP seems to have the somewhat rarer case of nested queries on the same table so this approach may not be helpful in that particular case.

```
val query = slickLoginInfos join slickUserLoginInfos on 
   ((l,ul) => l.id === ul.loginInfoId) 
db.run((for { (l, ul) <- query } yield (ul)).result.headOption)
```